# HTML Email template Mailchimp, CSS problems in Outlook and Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, templates, mailchimp

I've developed HTML Email template and imported to Mailchimp. It works perfect in testing mode. When I send it, Gmail, Outlook and Windows Mail have problems with CSS style loading. It shows only HTML.

Then I tried to develop with tables without linking CSS, again perfect in Mailchimp testing and problems Gmail, Outlook and Windows Mail. As  there are not loading even STYLE attribute of tables.

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Email Design</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
 <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" background="img/beton.jpg" style="">
 <tr>
  <td >
 <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="160" height=auto align="right"  style="padding: 49px 60px; 0 0; left:548px; display: block;" />
 <a href="facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="50" height=auto align="right"  style="padding: 39px 0px 0 0px; 0 0; left:548px; display: block;" /></a>
       <img src="img/newsletter_h1.png" alt="Creating Email Magic" width="342" height=auto align="left"  style="padding: 0px 00px; 0 0; display: block;" />


</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >
   Row 2
  </td>
 <tr>
  <td >
   Row 3
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

        <div></div>
</body>




</html>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Email does not work the same as a web page. Email is like building a table HTML4 web page. Here is a guide to CSS in Email client support: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - Also its worth testing your emails with something like email on acid:https://www.emailonacid.com/

Comment: There are alot of constraints when coding email templates, you should take a look at mailchimps documentation about email client support > https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/ You should also reset the padding/margin on all your <td>'s, avoid using short hand css too.

Comment: You have to use always inline CSS. If css is in the head section often client email ignore it.

Comment: If you have a version of your HTML with a fully path to your CSS (not a relative path) you can paste it into Mailchimp's "CSS Inliner" tool.  Would be quicker and possibly save you some errors hand-coding it. https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: I don't know why, Gmail skips even inline style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe issue in header type in mail. Please check your headers as per below.

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```